# R - converting recursive code to functional programming

Tags: r, recursion, functional-programming, reduce, higher-order-functions

I want to do a conditional cumsum. I originally thought I could use the Reduce function but I wasnt able to. To explain clearly :

```
a <- rep(1,5)
b <- rnorm(n=5,mean=0.5)
c <- rep(2,5)
d <- rep(0.5,5)

Reduce( '+', a, init=200 , accumulate=TRUE)
```

Results in

```
[1] 200 201 202 203 204 205
```

This is just like a simple cumsum. But what I actually want is a conditional cumsum:

The recursion is defined as :

```
 x0 = 200
 index = 0

 function (x) {
   index = index + 1
   if( x is between 200 and 202 ) return x + a[index]
   else if(x is between 202 and 204) return x + b[index]
   else if(x is between 204 and 206) return x + c[index]
   else return x + d[index]

 }
```

The expected result could be something like this (of course it will never be the same because of the randomness.

```
  [1] 200 201 202.3 203.8 204.1 205
```

For those who are interested, the answer can be found here : 
[Convert simple recursive relation to functional program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15506060/convert-simple-recursive-relation-to-functional-program)

I can't seem to find a way to mark this question as *closed* since the moderators keep on deleting whatever I add without suggesting a proper way to close.

Comment: I don't understand how is this recursion? Also your example needs to be more clear. Give exact desired result as an example as well. Don't just describe it.

Comment: I have clarified the recursion by putting it in function format. Of course there is no clear "expected answer" because there is randomness involved. I can maybe make it clearer by using some fixed values if you like, but I dont want the readers to answer using a fixed mathematical formula, I want to understand how to do this using Higher Order functions.

Comment: @user1480926 I don't think that this a job for Reduce. First you can't give a matrix to Reduce. You can just give a vector(maybe you can create a vector where you alternate between a and b) Second your index variable must be a global one , something like `index <<- index +1`...

Comment: thanks @agstudy, so is there no way to use an elegant higher order function while dealing with data more complex than a mere vector in R ?

Comment: @user1480926 I can't say that there isn't. I am saying that it is not a `Reduce` job, at least as you present it. Do you have a big workflow  where you try to alternate between 2 lists or just you want to learn `Reduce`?

Comment: @agstudy I have a bigger workflow - similar to what I have described above. The problem, in a nutshell, is a conditional cumsum that I want to accomplish without a loop. Reduce seemed right because I could define the problem using recursion, but perhaps if there are alternative higher order functions (such as variants of Filter or Map) that are better suited, I would love to know about them.

Comment: @user1480926 what is the condition? do  you update it dynamically? I mean in each iteration?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26181/discussion-between-agstudy-and-user1480926)

Comment: Hi @agstudy sorry I was away in a meeting. This condition is static but slightly more complex (e.g. multiple if thens instead of just two).

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you need `Reduce` here. Here an example that explain a use case of `Reduce`:

```
 Reduce(paste,list(1:3,letters[1:3],LETTERS[1:3]))
[1] "1 a A" "2 b B" "3 c C"
```

I think what you try to do xan be done using `ifelse`, it is vectorized. Here for example a conditional cumultive sum of a and b starting from init value.

```
a <- rep(1,5)
b <- rep(0.01,5)
init <- 200
x <- seq_along(a)
cumsum(c(init,ifelse( x %% 2 ,a[x],  b[x])))
[1] 200.00 201.00 201.01 202.01 202.02 203.02
```

Of course if you have multiple condition:

- Use multiple condition: `x %% 2 & x^2 < 5`
- Use nested `ifelse` : `ifelse( x %% 2 ,ifelse(x^2 <2, a[x], b[x]),1)`

Comment: hi agstudy what would be a clean way to do it for more ifs. For example :  if{  a } elseif {b } elseif{c} else{d} ? and more options other than a[x] b[x] (e.g. if I had a c[x], d[x] as well ?

Comment: @user1480926 Add the condition in pseudo code to your the OP I will help to write it.

Comment: @user1480926 I notice that you changed  the condition on `x`, now the condition is on x the result of cumsum? note on the index of x ....I think you can't do it with `ifelse` you need a `loop`!

Comment: yes that is why I sought to use a Reduce function in the first place, since I thought it tracks the prior result within the iteration and didnt want mathematical type solutions.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26226/discussion-between-agstudy-and-user1480926)